# Invalid initial expression type for field, expecting: Id

Tags: apex, trigger, map

I am getting an error on the groupId get statement. This is my first attempt to use maps. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
trigger UserPublicGroupMembership on User (after insert, after update ) {

    List<GroupMember> gpMember = new list<GroupMember>();

    List<Group> pubGroup = new list<Group>([
        Select Id,Name 
        FROM Group
    ]);    
    Map<Id, Group> gmap = new Map<Id, Group>(pubGroup);

    //Put user in group if insert
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(User u:trigger.new){

            IF (u.UserRole.Name == 'BCS Manager'){
                gpMember.add(new GroupMember(
                    UserOrGroupId = u.Id,
                    GroupId = gmap.get('BCS Managers')
                ));
            }

            //so on and so on for all our roles. 
        }
    }

    //Check if profile or role changed, then put user in group if true
    if(trigger.isUpdate){

    }

    //Nnow that list is populated insert. 
    //Always doing an insert as system doesn't care about existing membership conflicts. 
    Insert gpMember;

}
```

**Error Message:**

> Invalid initial expression type for field GroupMember.GroupId, expecting: Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `gmap.get(...)` it gives you back a `Group`. You need its Id instead, so use `gmap.get(...).Id`.

If you're not sure the record will exist, this pattern can cause a `QueryException`. In that case, it might be better to guard against such a case:

```
Group bcsGroup = gmap.get('BCS Managers');
if (bcsGroup != null)
{
    // intermediate logic
    GroupId = bcsGroup.Id
}
```

---

Also, note that you don't need to use so much boilerplate when performing queries. Just do:

```
List<Group> groups = [/*query*/];
```

Or if you just need the `Map`:

```
Map<Id, Group> gropus = new Map<Id, Group>([/*query*/]);
```

Comment: @Matt glad I could help.

Comment: @Matt Don't forget, if this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), to please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered.

Comment: yah sorry I meant to do that. You responded so fast with your answer I was within the time limit to accept your answer as best. I did it now.